# Error regarding function attribution in class (python)

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

I have a question regarding python class - function.
I have one class with three (including `__init__`) functions, output of each def is feed on to the next def.
The code below works until function (`a1`), but when I execute function (`a2`), I m getting the error below, and I have no idea why.

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'a2'
```

I am attaching the code below.

```
class Optimizer:
    
    def __init__(self,x_input, y_input,w1,w2,w3,b1,b2,b3,learn_rate):
        self.x = x_input
        self.y = y_input
        self.w1 = w1
        self.w2 = w2
        self.w3 = w3
        self.b1 = b1
        self.b2 = b2
        self.b3 = b3
        self.learn_rate = 2
        print("x input\n", self.x)
        print("y input", self.y)
        
    def a1(self):
        layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.w1, self.x) +self.b1)
        print("layer_1",layer_1)
        return layer_1
    
    def a2(self):
        layer_2 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.w2, self.layer_1) + self.b2)
        print("layer_2",layer_2)
        return layer_2
```

line

```
trial = Optimizer(x,y,w1,w2,w3,b1,b2,b3,2).a1()
```

works fine, no error

line

```
trial = Optimizer(x,y,w1,w2,w3,b1,b2,b3,2).a1().a2()
```

give the **No attribute** error.

Could anyone give me an insight???

Thank you

Comment: `Optimizer.a1()` returns `layer_1` what looks like being `numpy.ndarray`, not instance of `Optimizer`

Comment: The `a1` method returns `layer_1`, which is not an instance of the `Optimizer` class. Why do you think you can call `a2()` on it?

Comment: because a1 returns a numpy object and a2 is a method for an Optimizer object that's why the error

Comment: If you want to be able to chain methods like this, you need to use `return self`.

Answer (score 0):

#### ⚠️ This code behaviour is generaly considered as a bad practice in Python, consider different calls like this:

```py
optimizer = Optimizer(x,y,w1,w2,w3,b1,b2,b3,2)
layer_1 = optimizer.a1()
layer_2 = optimizer.a2(layer_1)
```

## Return self in `a1()`

`sigmoid` return a numpy array, so if you want to chain call, you need to return the `self`. Also, to store the result of sigmoid, you may have to store it in an attribute.

```py
    def a1(self):
        self.layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.w1, self.x) +self.b1)
        print("layer_1", self.layer_1)
        return self
```

Comment: Really, it makes more sense to return the computed value than to cache it just to accommodate this kind of weird method chaining.

Comment: @chepner I agree. I don't like method chaining, but users of numpy and pandas are often crazy with method chaining, so I won't fight against that ;)

Comment: That's partly because answers like this normalize the behavior. Stop reinforcing the idea that this is a sane way to write code.

Comment: (Retracting my downvote, as it does explain *how* the OP's expected behavior is achieved, but you should emphasize that this is not a good way to write code in Python.)

Comment: This is mostly because pandas and numpy works this way, except with in_place argument. Yes, it's not a good practice, but this isn't code review. I'll add a warning in the answer.

Comment: @chepner "but you should emphasize that this is not a good way to write code in Python" 100% agree, will do, thanks for your help !